# Problem of array index when querying the database with Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem when I run this method :

```
    public function getNutritionalValuesPerMeal($item,$nutritionalValues){

        foreach (array($nutritionalValues) as $key => $value) {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $item->nutritionalValue->attributes)) {
                $nutritionalValues[$key] += $item->nutritionalValue->attributes[$key];
            }
        }
        return $nutritionalValues;
    }
```

The exception thrown is the following :
[image]

When I dd the variables I got this.

- For $item->nutritionalValue :

[image]

- For $item->nutritionalValue['calories'] :

[image]

- For $nutritionalValues :

[image]

What I do not understand is that $item->nutritionalValue['calories'] is correctly dd but the console is telling me that the index of calories can not be found. What is odd too is that no exception are thrown for the line :

```
$nutritionalValues['weight'] = $nutritionalValues['weight'] + $item->nutritionalValue['weight'];
```

I use Eloquent relationships to fetch nutritionalValue, which is a relationship with the ingredients.

Thanks for the help !

Edit : I am calling the function inside of a loop :

```
public function getNutritionalValuesPerDay($mealNutritionalValues,$items,$day){
    foreach($items as $item){
        switch ($item->pivot->meal) {
            case "Breakfast":
                $mealNutritionalValues["Breakfast"] = $this->getNutritionalValuesPerMeal($item,$mealNutritionalValues["Breakfast"]);
                break;
            case "Snack 1":
                $mealNutritionalValues["Snack 1"] = $this->getNutritionalValuesPerMeal($item,$mealNutritionalValues["Snack 1"]);
                break;
            case "Lunch":
                $mealNutritionalValues["Lunch"] = $this->getNutritionalValuesPerMeal($item,$mealNutritionalValues["Lunch"]);
                break;
            case "Snack 2":
                $mealNutritionalValues["Snack 2"] = $this->getNutritionalValuesPerMeal($item,$mealNutritionalValues["Snack 2"]);
                break;
            case "Dinner":
                $mealNutritionalValues["Dinner"] = $this->getNutritionalValuesPerMeal($item,$mealNutritionalValues["Dinner"]);
                break;
        }
    }
    return $mealNutritionalValues;
}
```

And now I have the error :
[image]

I don't see how is this possible because each array sent to this method is the same...

Edit 2 : Problem solved !

Comment: did you call this function inside for loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the scope and context of your method, the safest way to access the attributes is `$item->nutritionalValue->attributes['calories']`, etc. More info: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Why `dd()` can access that attribute - it is because `dd()` runs some sort of a `get()` method on the object.

Aside from that, I would refactor your method as following:

```
public function getNutritionalValuesPerMeal($item, $nutritionalValues)
{
    foreach ($nutritionalValues as $key => $value) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $item->nutritionalValue->attributes)) {
            $nutritionalValues[$key] += $item->nutritionalValue->attributes[$key];
        } 
    }
    return $nutritionalValues;
}
```

Comment: Hi, it worked for this function but now I have another index problem (see my edited post).. Thanks for the help though !